# Supersonic aircraft desire features

Tags: avionics

It is possible to modify a supersonic aircraft such as it can fly under the radar? If so, what are the three most important aspects to consider to be able to do this effectively?

Answer (score 1):

When flying at low level, under the radar waves from a ground installation, the air is very dense. So, if you want to fly fast, you need 1) low drag, and 2) high thrust. The third most important aspect is probably a flight control system that enables the aircraft to do this without possibly hitting the terrain, by not relying on only the pilot skills to fly safely. I nominate drag as the most important aspect, because it's better to minimise that than have to counter act with increased thrust. At supersonic speed, low drag is significantly achieved by swept wings that fall within the shock cone formed by the nose of the aircraft. The F-111 is an old design, but could fly supersonic at low level, had variable swing wings, and featured terrain following radar. So, it can/has been done. But..if the aircraft is already designed, the second and third aspects can be modified, but drag cannot be changed.